# can't find the grey margin in VBA editor where you apply breakpoints

Tags: vba, editor, breakpoints, margin-left

I somehow squeezed the margin where you apply breakpoints in the VBA editor. I can still apply breakpoints using shortcut keys but i can not scroll the control to a previous line without dragging it because i can't see the grey margin on left of code.

Comment: This question should be on SuperUser, as it does not specifically deal with the code, but the editor.

Comment: ^^ I agree (although I would love to know the answer, because I didn't even know that it was possible to resize that grey margin!)

Comment: Ahh - found it - Tools / Options / Editor Format / Margin Indicator Bar

Comment: @YowE3K might as well answer it.

Answer (score 8):

Visibility of the margin can be selected / unselected by going to Tools / Options / Editor Format / Margin Indicator Bar.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure whether that "red free-hand circle" is red enough - I'll probably get down-voted for it :D

Comment: The part I don't get is, who the heck thought it would be a good idea to make that *margin indicator bar* optional?!

Comment: @Mat'sMug you know there was that one guy, who sat in the planning and said, "I don't like it, I want the extra pixels in my code space."  we have all encountered "That Guy".

Comment: @ScottCraner To be honest, I never use that margin indicator bar, and I always curse when I click on it by accident and thus create a breakpoint, so perhaps I am "That Guy"!

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question. This would have been super hard if it weren't for you guys.